# Find elementts with stream api in pogo class

Tags: java-stream

I want to find all numbers `5, 5.5, 6, 6.5` that have quantity not null

It's pogo  of the first entity:

```java
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @ToString
        @EqualsAndHashCode
        public class Box {
        
            @SerializedName("id")
            private Integer id;
            @SerializedName("name")
            private String name;
            @SerializedName("sizes")
            private List<Size> sizes = null;
            @SerializedName("quantity")
            private Integer quantity;
            @SerializedName("quantityPerSize")
            private List<QuantityPerSize> quantityPerSize;
        }
```

It's pogo  of the second entity.

```java
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class QuantityPerSize {
    
        @SerializedName("id")
        private List<Integer> id = null;
        @SerializedName("qty")
        private Integer qty;
    }
```

It's pogo  of the therd  entity

```java
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class Size {
    
        @SerializedName("id")
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("name")
        private Name name;
        @SerializedName("sizeOrder")
        private Integer sizeOrder;
    }
```

It's photo of response:

[image]

It's my code. How I can get 5,5.5 with qt not null?

```java
box.stream()
   .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("korob")).forEach(quantityPerSize -> {
       if (quantityPerSize.getQty() != 0) {
            log.debug(box.getSizes().stream().filter(size -> size.getId().equals(quantityPerSize.getId())).iterator().next().getName().getEn());
       }
   });
```

Comment: How do you get a stream of quantityPerSize from a stream of boxes?

Comment: I think "pogo" means "pojo".